# ActiveRecord how to correctly exclude records with conditions correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Why does below not work? 
Try to exclude all the is_reply = 1 values from the query but can't figure out how to.
I tried several combinations but all fail.

All records with is_reply = 1 still get returned with this below query, I think need to sub the or part but how?

> @messages = Message.all(:conditions => ['is_reply = ? AND recipient_id
>   = ? OR user_id = ?', 0, current_user.id, current_user.id] )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use parenthesis`()` and group your conditions together

```
 ['is_reply = ? AND (recipient_id = ? OR user_id = ?)', 0, current_user.id, current_user.id]
```